# Unity XML text content included in build

Tags: xml, unity-game-engine

I have received the source files for a Unity game, I need to change some text in it. I have seen that nearly all of the text is included in an XML file.  Tried to make a small edit to it, build the game, but the old text is still showing up. I searched all source files and that text is only in one file.

Is there some special setting when doing the build to include the updated XML files? Is there any other process to run before so that the changes to the XML files are included in the game?

XML files and other scripts and code are included in a solution, not sure if that has to do with it.

I am quite new at Unity but I am quite puzzled by this.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities to solve your problem.

1. Save project. Restart Unity3D Editor.
   This is cause text resources aren't refreshed in Unity3D since few versions. I mean you wan't see changes until you follow these steps. BTW saving project could be all you need, but try also with restarting.
2. Text really isn't in the xml file, but is assigned through inspector to public string field. That way you cannot find it in project, as text is visible only in inspector.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have the code you could initlize the xml with the values you want, or make a post build process method to open the xml,modify the xml and save it - on build.
for more information : [see this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Callbacks.PostProcessBuildAttribute.html)